# Copying the first 'n' files from each subfolder Unix

Tags: shell, file, unix, directory, scripting

My folder structure is as follows :
[image: Folder structure]
and so on.

How do I copy the first file from each folder and rename them (maybe with the parent folder's name) so as to not ending up replacing them?

P.S :

1. I want to store them in a new folder with the same sub directories as source but with just one  .wav file in each. And yes, in shell script or
2. Main_Folder/sub_folder_1/abc.wav
   Main_Folder/sub_folder_1/def.wav

   Main_Folder/sub_folder_2/abc.wav
   Main_Folder/sub_folder_2/def.wav

   Main_Folder/sub_folder_3/abc.wav
   Main_Folder/sub_folder_3/def.wav

This folder structure repeats for all the sub_folders under the main_folder.

I want the output to look like :

```
New_Main_Folder/sub_folder_1/abc.wav
New_Main_Folder/sub_folder_2/abc.wav
New_Main_Folder/sub_folder_3/abc.wav
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the result folder structure that you want. Also, please include the input folder structure in the question (not as an image!)

Comment: Also, do all folders under `Main Folder` contain files that you want to copy the first file from? (and do each of the folders contain files?) The problem you will have is "What is first?" based on? Sort order can vary by LOCALE, so using a glob doesn't provide a guaranteed order and you don't use `ls` for this type of operation. `find` is unsorted. You can sort the files in each folder by some criteria before taking the first file (or first X number of files) Please provide more details.

Comment: I assume you want to write a shell script to do this -- if not, let us know.

Comment: I tried to clean up your post, but for some reason the sections in between the `.....` segments seem to honor `{}` formatting in the preview, but only display as wrapped lines in the posted view. Arg! Generally speaking we use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. AGREE with above, please don't post images and expect readers to goto external sites to understand your problem. Best to include code like `mkdir test1 test2 ; for dir in * ; do (cd dir ; for file in a b c ; do touch $file; done ) ; done` (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, the image business is the handiwork of stackoverflow (it doesnt let me upload an image in-line since I do not have enough karma points!)

Comment: Arg. I messed up and didn't rollback to the right level. I think now I have your Q containing your previous best effort to describe your problem. You can however delete the link to the `.png` file and make an ascii-art representation of your problem. OR as I mentioned above, let people make a test environment that matches your problem using `mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3 ....` and then populate each dir with a group of files. Finally, in the current state, you're asking people to write code for you. You need to include your best attempt to solve your problem. ....

Comment: Again, Sorry to have messed your Q up. As many people only look at the newest Qs, you might do better to delete this and repost a new one, following my suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432122/how-to-exclude-subdirectories-of-a-specific-directory-from-find-command for an example of ascii-art file structures.