# How to exclude subdirectories of a specific directory from find command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I'm trying to get a list of files which I can pipe to `wc -l` to get a word count of all of them (not using `wc` directly so I can filter the file list before using the command).

My directory structure is something like this:

```
- folder
   - file.php
   - file2.html
   - file3.php
   - folder1
   - folder2a
   - folder3b
   - folder4
- file.php
- file2.php
```

I'd like to exclude certain directories in my `find`, largely libraries and other stuff that I didn't make. I can do that manually like so:

`find /var/www/html/ -type f -not -path "/var/www/html/folder/folder1" -not -path "/var/www/html/folder/folder2a"` etc.

However, it's being annoying to have to explicitly specify all the folders, and the list could change at any point, too. I've tried using `/*` and `/**` to pattern match but that doesn't work, either. **Is there a way for one of these "not"s in my find command that I can exclude all the subdirectories of a particular directory, but *not* exclude that directory itself?** (include its files, but not any of its subdirectories)?

Here's an intuitive guess:

```
find /var/www/html -not -path '/var/www/html/someotherbadfolder' -type f \( ! -path "/var/www/html/folder" -maxdepth 1 \)
```

But even `find` complains about this:

```
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -not, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
```

So it seems `maxdepth` is incapable of being combined in an operation.

There's lots of Q&A about excluding specific subdirectories, but not generically any subdirectories in a particular subdirectory.

I was able to get it to work in a single directory with `-maxdepth 1`,  but the problem is this is an exclusion part of a larger command, and that didn't work once I ran the full command. Potentially, I might need to exclude specific subdirectories as well as any subdirectories in several other specific subdirectories.

Comment: `find /var/www/html -type d -path '/var/www/html/folder/*' -prune -o -type f -print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just with find:

```sh
find /var/www/html -type f -not -path '/var/www/html/folder/*/*'
```

Original answer:

One hack could be `grep -v` on the output of find:

```sh
find /var/www/html/ -type f | grep -v "/var/www/html/folder/.*/" | wc -l
```

Comment: This is perfect! I just needed to add `xargs` before the `wc` and it did what I was looking for. I think I can just pipe multiple times, once for each folder with subdirectories that needs to be excluded, and exclude the other subdirectories as part of the find.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're specifically looking for files (i.e. not directories):

```
find /var/www/html -type f -not -path "/var/www/html/folder/*/*"
```

That's because:

- files directly under `/var/www/html/folder` aren't directories so they don't match the `-path` clause.
- directories directly under `/var/www/html/folder` don't match `-type f`.
- files under subdirectories of `/var/www/html/folder` has to have the extra `/` in the path, so they match the `-path` expression.

Comment: You're right, I haven't tested this case, answer fixed.